# C#: Как извлечь перевод длинного текста из ответа Google Translate?

Tags: c#

Есть метод для перевода текста через Google Translate без использования `API v2`, то есть через обычный `WebClient`.

Метод принимает аргументы `text` - исходный текст и `to` - язык, на который нужно перевести текст. Язык исходного текста задается как `"auto"`, то есть должен определяться автоматически.

```cs
public static string Translate(string text, string to)
{
   var url = $"https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl={to}&dt=t&q={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text)}";
   var webClient = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
   var result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
   try
   {
       result = result.Substring(4, result.IndexOf("\"", 4, StringComparison.Ordinal) - 4);
       return result;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"Transalte Error: {e.Message}");
       return null;
   }
}
```

---

**Проблема:**

С простым текстом из нескольких слов все работает отлично, но если задать текст из нескольких строк (с содержанием `\n`) или предложений, то метод возвращает перевод только первого предложения.

**Причина:**

Это происходит потому что Google Translate возвращает перевод отдельных предложений (или строк (`\n`)) не в одной строке, а в нескольких.

Например, при вызове метода с такими входным данными

```cs
string text = @"Нижняя сторона крыльев менее яркая, но более пёстрая. Она коричневато-бурая, с разнообразными красноватыми и белыми пятнами и серыми разводами. Снизу на передних крыльях повторяется рисунок верхней стороны, который дополняется голубыми кольцами в центральной ячейке. Нижняя сторона задних крыльев коричневатая, с замысловатым мраморовидным рисунком, образованным за счет тёмных штрихов и извилистых линий. Также у переднего края заднего крыла находится светлое пятно";
Translate(text, "en");
```

Метод вернет только первое предложение

```
"The underside of the wings is less bright, but more variegated. "
```

А результат будет таким:

```
[[["The underside of the wings is less bright, but more variegated. ","Нижняя сторона крыльев менее яркая, но более пёстрая.",null,null,3,null,null,[[]],[[["d79f3353813f458ef00a8442f9b7b2b6","ru_en_2022q1.md"]]]],["It is brownish-brown, with a variety of reddish and white spots and gray stains. ","Она коричневато-бурая, с разнообразными красноватыми и белыми пятнами и серыми разводами.",null,null,3,null,null,[[]],[[["d79f3353813f458ef00a8442f9b7b2b6","ru_en_2022q1.md"]]]],["From below on the forewings, the pattern of the upper side is repeated, which is complemented by blue rings in the central cell. ","Снизу на передних крыльях повторяется рисунок верхней стороны, который дополняется голубыми кольцами в центральной ячейке.",null,null,3,null,null,[[]],[[["d79f3353813f458ef00a8442f9b7b2b6","ru_en_2022q1.md"]]]],["The underside of the hindwings is brownish, with an intricate marble-like pattern formed by dark strokes and sinuous lines. ","Нижняя сторона задних крыльев коричневатая, с замысловатым мраморовидным рисунком, образованным за счет тёмных штрихов и извилистых линий.",null,null,3,null,null,[[]],[[["d79f3353813f458ef00a8442f9b7b2b6","ru_en_2022q1.md"]]]],["There is also a light spot at the anterior edge of the hind wing.","Также у переднего края заднего крыла находится светлое пятно",null,null,3,null,null,[[]],[[["d79f3353813f458ef00a8442f9b7b2b6","ru_en_2022q1.md"]]]]],null,"ru",null,null,null,1,[],[["ru"],null,[1],["ru"]]]
```

В то время как текст из одного предложения метод вернет корректно, потому что есть всего одно предложение.

**Попытки решения:**

Я пробовал заменять символы переноса строки и возврата каретки на `\n`->`\\n` и `\r`->`\\r`, а затем в получившемся тексте возвращать их обратно и это работало, но как мне кажется, это не совсем правильное решение. Тем более, что текст с точками (из нескольких предложений) все равно возвращается в виде одного предложения и точки так будет заменять некорректно.

В `Python` по этому объекту можно было бы просто пробежаться циклом `for` как по списку и получить нужные данные, но в `C#` из-за строгой типизации я даже не представляю как десериализовать этот объект.

Может быть есть еще какой-то способ?

Comment: А при чем тут `\n`? Вам в ответе приходит JSON, который содержит массив строк, вы вместо того, чтобы нормально с ним работать, непойми зачем кастрируете строку через `result.Substring(...)`. Десериализируйте JSON как положено, у вас тогда будет массив массивов, в котором просто берите 2-е значение и все. И да, `WebClient` - устаревший класс в C# языке!

Comment: Проблема в том, что я уже пробовал десериализовать это через `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object[][]>(result)`, но это просто не работает. Также как и при попытке десериализовать к типу `dynamic`. Может нужно создать какой-то дополнительный класс для десериализации?

Comment: Ну, у вас очень грязный JSON, прям очень получается, из за чего вам либо с корверторами возиться (смотреть где массив, где строка, а где null), либо полностью отбрасывать все, что не подходит. Вот допустим пример с Json.NET [написал вам](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E1dwoh), как видите, ВСЕ ошибки десериализации я отбрасываю, а из полученного беру 1-й объект каждого массива, в итоге будет простой массив строк. Как делать такое на `System.Text.Json` смотрите сами)

Comment: Я попробовал написать вот такой класс для десериализации, где все ненужные элементы пометил как `object` и назвал `temp`. Сверху чуть подробнее расписал структуру json-объекта, почему так не получается? https://pastebin.com/hY609LEV

Comment: А зачем вам тут классы? У вас в JSON есть классы? Или свойства? Классы в Json это `"SomeClass": { ... }`, а свойства `"SomeProp" : "Value"`. У вас такого как видите нету, у вас просто массивы из разных типов данных (может быть строка, может быть null, может быть массив, может быть массив из массивов, и так далее), ну и тут, как я вам писал выше, выход только один - делать конвертор, который будет определять что именно за тип и в него перегонять. Ну, либо как опять же, я написал вам выше, игнорировать все ошибки десериализации, тогда у вас будет не полный JSON, но он вам и не нужен.

Comment: Тогда еще проще `var result = json[0].Select(x => x[0] as string);`, но учтите, если 0-го индекса не будет, будет ошибка, стоит это обработать.

Comment: Это json, не изобратайте,есть готовые велосипеды. WebClient тоже надо закопать туда, откуда откопали.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ оформите это как решение что ли - работает же)

Comment: @aepot а на что заменить его?

Comment: @denisnumb Отвечать не буду, уж извиняйте. Можете оформить его сами из того, что получили.

Comment: На `HttpClient`, примеры есть прямо в документации по классу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Благодаря [`@EvgeniyZ`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz) получилось такое решение:**

Поскольку JSON-ответ от Google Translate проблемно десериализовать стандартными методами от `System.Json.Text`, решением стал конвертер через`Newtonsoft.Json`:

```cs
// здесь result - это полный ответ от Google Translate
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[][][]>(result, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
{
  Error = (_, e) => { e.ErrorContext.Handled = true; }
});

// здесь берем элемент с индексом 1, то есть строку с переведенным текстом
// а затем выполняем вход отдельных предложений в строку через пробел
// с заменой `\n ` на `\n`, чтобы текст в новой строке не начинался с пробела
result = string.Join(" ", json[0].SelectMany(x => x.Skip(0)?.Take(1)).Cast<string>()).Replace("\\n", "\n").Replace("\n ", "\n");
```